# Changes to specific row of buttons (toolbar buttons) in helperList prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am creating a helperList in prestashop. On list creation I noticed a specific row of buttons (toolbar buttons) on top right corner of the helperList that provided functionalities regarding database. Is it possible to modify those buttons and give them functions according to our own needs? I have added an image of the helperList that I have created and marked those buttons with red squares.[image: Row of buttons in helperList.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to it. They can be modified by overriding the toolbar of helperList prestashop.

```
public function initToolbar() {
    parent::initToolbar();

    $this->toolbar_btn['new'] = array(
        'href' => $this->context->link->getAdminLink('some link'),
        'desc' => $this->l('some description')
    );
}
```